# Printing Labels using CSS with Floated List

Tags: html, css, printing

I'm trying to re-make an existing ASP.Net page which generates labels. The original uses hideous tables-within tables-within tables to force a layout, and as our order quantity has increased it's now got to the point where it's spitting out 65k lines of HTML assuming it doesn't time out first.

I've replaced it with an unordered list for my list of lables, with each list item floated, and the on-screen layout is now perfect. For print, it's 4 labels per page, one in each corner.

However, at least in IE-land, go to print preview and it goes back to being a vertical list.

Any thoughts?

Comment: how are you setting your dimensions? Could it be that the labels just don't fit next to each other?

Comment: IE 8, but just noticed same behaviour in Chrome and Firefox

Comment: Dimensions are identical to the existing ones, set in CSS as exact pixel values. They should exactly fit, same as currently.

Comment: Do you have any stray `@media` settings in the CSS or `media` attributes on the `<style>` tags?

Comment: Yep, only the references to the external stylesheets specify media="print", no other media attributes. No @media in the stylesheet itself. No style tags, all done via CSS classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed from UL/LI elements to the ubiquitous DIV, and placed every set of 4 inside a container which did the job. Still none the wiser about why FireFox, Chrome and IE all ignored float:left in print though, but it's working now.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you are using a float:... in your css of li class it will fix it :)

Let me know if that helps

Comment: Hi, the li definition is already floated, and displays correctly on screen, just not in print/print preview, when they drop back to vertical.

Comment: try adding display: inline-block; and then preview this is a knwon bug with IE print preivew. that might solves it for u

Comment: Nope... that now displays in a vertical list on-screen as well (was using display: inline before)